# 5 CPU's Task scheduling N process

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Question.**

> There are 5 CPUs and N number of tasks in the queue. You have to use
>   minimum CPUs to process the tasks.
>
> A task is of format [arrival time, time to process the task].
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. You can only use at most 5 CPUs. If it is not possible in 5 CPUs, print -1.
> 2. The time to process the task should not be greater than 10     i.e (Time waiting in queue + time to process the task) <= 10.
> 3. If to process the current task, you need more than 10 seconds in current CPU, you can move to a different CPU and check if it is
>      possible to process the task in <=10 time.
> 4. If it is not possible to process the task in <=10 or at most 5 CPUs, print -1.

**Constraints.**

> 0 <= Arrival time <= 500
>
> 1 <= time to process the task <= 10
>
> 0 <= N <=500
>
> You can only use iostream library. No STL's are allowed.
>
> Time : 3 second for T test cases

**Eg:-**

> Input
>
> 3
>
> 1 6
>
> 2 7
>
> 3 1
>
> Output
>
> 2

**Explanation:**

> 3   - N
>
> 1 6 - the first task arrives in CPU0 at time 1, and leaves at time 7 (1+6). 
>    CPUs used = 1.
>
> 2 7 - the second task arrives in CPU0 at time 2, and wait for 5
>   seconds in the queue, so overall processing time is 5+7 > 10. So it is
>   moved to CPU1. CPUs used = 2.
>
> 3 1  -  the third task arrives. it can go to CPU0 or CPU1, as
>   processing time is 5 `( (7-3) + 1 )` and 7 `( (9-3) + 1 )`   seconds respectively. CPUs used = 2.
>
> CPU1 is a fresh CPU. So task2 will be completed in 9 `(2 + 7)` seconds without any Time to wait in the queue.

**My Approach:**

1. Initially, thought this as a variant of `minimum train-platform problem`. But that was wrong.
2. Tried a `greedy` approach, but it gave -1 for some valid solutions.

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 500

int N;
int arr[MAXN];
int len[MAXN];

int main(){

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    cin>>N;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>> arr[i] >> len[i];
    }


    int exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[5]={0};
    int cpus_used_so_far=1;

    int min_processing_time;
    int min_processing_time_idx;

    for(int task_idx=0; task_idx<N; task_idx++){

        min_processing_time = INT_MAX;
        min_processing_time_idx = -1;

        // finds the CPU which can process task in minimum time.
        for(int i=0; i<cpus_used_so_far ; i++){

            int processing_time = 0;
            int time_in_queue = exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] - arr[task_idx];

            if( time_in_queue < 0 ) // ie processor is free before arrival
                time_in_queue = 0;

            processing_time = time_in_queue + len[task_idx];

            if( processing_time <=10){
               if(processing_time < min_processing_time){
                    min_processing_time     = processing_time;
                    min_processing_time_idx = i;
               }
            }
        }

        if( min_processing_time_idx == -1){
            // No Existing CPU can solve this task.
            // Check if spawning a new CPU is possible.
            if (cpus_used_so_far+1 <= 5){
                //spawn a new CPU
                cpus_used_so_far++;
                int new_cpu_index = cpus_used_so_far - 1; // last CPU, converting to zero index

                exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index] = arr[task_idx] + len[task_idx] ;

            }else{
                cpus_used_so_far = -1; // not possible to spawn a new CPU,
                break;          //and you can't process with existing CPUs
            }

        }else{
            // Possible to handle with existing CPUs
            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[min_processing_time_idx] = arr[task_idx] + min_processing_time;
        }

    }


    cout << cpus_used_so_far <<endl;


}
```

3. Trying `memoization` approach.

Recursive approach solves the problem, but it gets timed out. (No wonder)

What is the possible way to save the state of `int`, `int`, `int[]`?

I am also open to an iterative solution for the same.

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 500

int min_cpus_used = 6;

int N;
int arr[MAXN];
int len[MAXN];

void recurse( int task_idx, int cpus_used_so_far, int  exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[] ){

    if( task_idx == N-1){
        min_cpus_used = min( min_cpus_used, cpus_used_so_far);
        return ;
    }

    if( cpus_used_so_far >= min_cpus_used ){
        return ; //optimization
    }

    for(int i=0; i<cpus_used_so_far ; i++){

        int processing_time = 0;
        int time_in_queue = exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] - arr[task_idx];

        if( time_in_queue < 0 ) // ie processor is free before arrival
            time_in_queue = 0;

        processing_time = time_in_queue + len[task_idx];

        // try with existing CPUs
        if( processing_time <=10){
            int prev =  exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i];
            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] = arr[task_idx] + processing_time;

            recurse( task_idx + 1 , cpus_used_so_far , exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs ); // can we optimize passing array

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] = prev;

        }

        // try with new CPU
        if (cpus_used_so_far+1 <= 5){

            int new_cpu_index = cpus_used_so_far + 1 - 1; // converting to zero index

            int prev = exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index];

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index] = arr[task_idx] + len[task_idx] ;

            recurse( task_idx+1 , cpus_used_so_far+1 , exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs );

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index] = prev;

        }else{
            return ;
        }

    }

}



int main(){

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    cin>>N;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>> arr[i] >> len[i];
    }

    int exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[5]={0};
    recurse(0, 1, exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs);

    if(min_cpus_used==6){
        cout<< -1 <<endl;
    }else{
        cout << min_cpus_used <<endl;
    }

}
```

Kindly help me with your thoughts on optimizing this solution.

PS:  This has nothing to do with CPU Scheduling.

Comment: "You can only use iostream library. No STL's are allowed." <-- I hate these kind of assignments. It's like "We want you to learn to ride a bicycle, but you're not allowed to use a saddle". As if you're every going to have a job where you cannot use STL...

Comment: @JHBonarius sorry for the confusion, it is 3 1. Corrected the question. This is a part of upsolving. So the question might have some mistakes(as I am trying to recreate it). But I tried my best to explain the question. Kindly let me know, if there is more info required.

Comment: I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the correct StackExchange site for this question. Maybe you should go to [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298212/where-to-ask-competitive-programming-related-problems-actually
There it was mentioned that, SO would be fine, if tagged under algorithm.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you. Will definitely move this to the mentioned forums, if couldn't get any help from here.

Comment: @JHBonarius when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I know, but I think that is a bad thing. Of course you have to spread your chances. Especially when posting to specific domain site. Else you will get questions that are down-voted a lot, like the OP (and I with a question on Math SE) experienced, and you'll never get an answer. Sometimes it's just not fully clear where you should ask something and how to formulate it.

Comment: It's a very strange assignment. On one hand you can apply any standard solver because you have the full input dataset from the beginning, on the other hand it's about CPU scheduling, which usually needs a heuristic approach as you normally can't predict the future.

Comment: @rustyx it is less inclined towards CPU scheduling. The idea is to do a DP on the input set, and find the least number of CPUs. But without getting timed out.

Comment: I think I know what DP means, but I don't understand it in this context :P . Maybe you should elaborate.

Comment: @JHBonarius The code here loops through the entire search space. Yes, it is not DP, because, I am not saving any state. But what is the possible solution to save the state? Can this be done recursively?

Comment: @JHBonarius Dynamic Programming.

Comment: I had an answer, but that was just straightforward. But this seems to be more "find the optimal way to distribute tasks over CPUs using computer programming theory". I also don't understand the 10 second rule: do all N=500 tasks have to be completed in 10 seconds? 5*10 = 50, that will never fit.

Comment: There will be T test cases. Say 5 test cases. Each test case will have N (1 <= N <= 500 ). T test cases have a maximum time limit of 3 seconds. PS: This has nothing to do with CPU scheduling. This is a DP problem. For simplicity, I have only included 1 test case.

Comment: Why do you say it's a DP problem? It's a combinatorial optimization problem. You need to research how to solve [scheduling problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem). Some possible techniques are: stochastic optimization, genetic algorithms, colony optimization, simulated annealing, Tabu search, and coordinate descent.

Comment: Do you have a link to the other cases? I have code that works for your test case, but I'd like to test it for the others. Please @ me.

Comment: As I have told you. This is a recreation of a question ( I am Upsolving). I don't have any link to the problem.

Comment: Wow, that attitude is not going to bring you anywhere. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: What kind of greedy algorithm did you use? I think this problem can indeed be solved with a greedy algorithm (after you brute force the limit on CPUs) after you split each task of length `K` into multiple tasks of unit length which appear simultaneously.

Comment: @yeputons Updated the post with my `greedy` code. We `can't` split the task. A single task has to be processed in single CPU.

Comment: @gnat: frown [5 CPU's Task scheduling N process](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196549/93149)? Or cross-posting without even cross-linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**: bruteforce the answer (maximal number of CPUs), sort tasks by start time, assign them to CPUs in that order with DP with profile (profile is the nearest moment when a specific CPU is available; ignore order of CPUs).

The solution is rather sophisticated. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

**Idea 1**: let's brute force maximal number of CPUs and brute force it (or apply binary search:
if `A` CPUs are enough, then `A+1` CPUs are enough as well).
Now we have a fixed number of CPUs and we have to solve a yes/no problem: is it
possible to arrange tasks execution in such and such way?
AS we have 5 CPUs max, that idea can be implemented with a simple outer for loop.

**Idea 2**: there is a solution which starts processing of any task at integer moment of time.

Proof: take any solution, choose the leftmost task for which that condition does not hold,
and notice that one can move it further to the left.
That reduces total sum of positions of all tasks.
Now let's choose the solution which minimizes that value.
It cannot have any tasks which start at non-integer times.

**Idea 3**: there is a solution with the following condition on each CPU:
for every try tasks `A` and `B` such that `A` is executed right before `B`,
`A` occurs in the sorted list of tasks earlier than `B` (sorted by their arrival/creation time).

Proof: take an arbitrary solution and bubble-sort tasks on each CPU.
We have to prove that swapping two adjacent tasks does not make the solution incorrect.
Consider tasks `A` and `B` such that `A` goes after `B` in the sorted list.
That means that its creation time is not greater than `B`'s creation time,
so `B` exists at the time we started processing `A`.
That also means that `A`'s desired termination time is not greater than `B`'s creation time,
so at the time `B` is completed we're still allowed to complete `A`.
So, swapping their order of execution does not make the solution incorrect and
we're free to do so.

**Idea 4**: it's possible to build a solution by starting with empty execution
plans for all CPUs and then appending tasks one-by-one to some plans, starting
from the earliest arrived and finished with the latest arrived task.
We append task to the lestmost possible time it can be started on a given CPU.

Proof: take an arbitrary solution with the property from idea 3.
Note that execution plan of each CPU is a subsequence of the sorted list of tasks.
Well, that means that each task in the sorted list can be assigned to a CPU,
and after performing the algorithm from idea 4 we will end up with some execution plan.
It'll be "no worse" than our original solution: positions of all tasks will be not
greater than positions of tasks in the original plan.
Therefore, that plan is also a solution.

**Idea 5**: run recursive backtracking to find distribution of tasks among CPUs.
We already know order in which they should be added to CPUs (the order of creation).
Keep track of first available time on each CPU and brute force assignment of
the next task on each step of the search. E.g. for tasks of length 1, 5, 2, 9, 3 starting at zero, the assignment may be:

```
Task start:   0 0 0 0 0
Task length:  1 5 2 9 3
Assigned CPU: A B B A B
```

**Idea 6**: add memoization (aka convert backtracking to dynamic programming).
Note that we don't really care if first available time on CPU is less than next
task's starting time `X`, and it also can't be greater than `X+10`.
So, we have 11 possibilities for each CPU, that's `11^5=161051` possibilities
for 5 CPUs.
That's the "profile" of our DP.
Since we don't care about order of CPUs, answers for profiles which differ
by permutation only are the same.
So we can consider 3003 different profiles only (that's `\choose{10+5}{5}`).
Another variable in our state is the number of the next task (500 possibilities),
and we also have 5 transitions from each state (which CPU to use).
That makes `3003*500*5 ~ 8m` transitions, which is not a big number, so we
can happily smash it under our outer for-loop from idea 1.
Of course, it'd better to precalculate transitions between profiles, but it
may also be possible to go without that.

Comment: Avoid **tl;dr:** in your answer, it's meaningless and adds nothing -- further, if you didn't read the entire question, you can't provide an accurate answer. Don't let something like that detract from an answer that otherwise shows good effort and is well formatted.

Comment: We don't know the order in which tasks should be added to CPUs. Consider 2 CPUs, `A` and `B`, were started with tasks `(0,5)` and `(0,8)` (meaning `(start-time, length)`, respectively. Now we have two other tasks, `(6, 6)` and `(7,7)`, followed by `(14, 10)` and another `(14,10)`. If we assign `(6,6)` first to either CPU, we are forced to start a third CPU. But if we assign `(7,7)` first to CPU `A` and then `(6,6)` to CPU `B`, those tasks would both end at 14, allowing our two `(14,10)` tasks to execute on CPUs `A` and `B` without requiring a third CPU.

Comment: @גלעדברקן , I'm sorry, I don't get your example. It's not required to assign tasks to CPUs in some specific order of CPUs (order of tasks is fixed, though). You can assign `(6,6)` to `B` first, and then assign `(7,7)` to `A`. Take an arbitrary order of tasks sorted by start time: `(0,5), (0,8), (6,6), (7, 7), (14, 10), (14, 10)`. Assign them to the following CPUs: ABBAAB, starting times will be 0, 0, 8, 7, 14, 14.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've probably used it in an unusual meaning ("short summary", see second meaning [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR)). Fixed for clarity, thanks.

Comment: I see. I thought by "order" of tasks you meant we know which task's starting time would come before another task's starting time. In `ABBAAB; 0, 0, 8, 7, 14`, the starting times of tasks 3 and 4 are out of order.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "We already know order in which they should be added to CPUs?"

Comment: @גלעדברקן ah, I've mixed up "start time" and "arrival/creation time". We sort tasks by their arrival/creation time, and then append them to CPUs in that order. That way we can obtain any assignment of tasks which preserves their relative order inside each CPU. Optimal assignment with such property exists as per idea 3. Tried to clarify it in the answer as well.

Comment: Just a thought, if you sort by arrival time, would this problem then reduce to merging intervals? where every merge/find overlapping intervals, where a merge/overlap corresponds to +1 cpu count?

Comment: @SamerTufail not sure what you mean. A task is not an interval - it's an interval which can be slightly moved forward, if needed. However, if we manage to find optimal positions, then minimal number of CPUs is equal to the maximal number of simultaneously overlapping intervals.

Comment: @yeputons we can define it as an interval say a task `[1 6]` is actually `[1 7]`, `[2 7]` is `[2 9]` and `[3 1]` is `[3 4]` - So when you merge the intervals there are 2 intervals which can be merged so 2 cpus. [1 7] [2 9] -> [1 9] first overlap and [3 4] the second. Need a few more test cases to prove/disprove this.

Comment: It is somewhat similar to this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/process-tasks-using-servers/