# Finding 2 equal sum sub-sequences, with maximum sum?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> I have removed all the storylines for this question.
>
> `Q.` You are given N numbers. You have to find 2 equal sum sub-sequences, with maximum sum. You don't necessarily need to use all numbers.

**Eg 1:-**

```
5
1 2 3 4 1

Sub-sequence 1 : 2 3 // sum = 5
Sub-sequence 2 : 4 1 // sum = 5

Possible Sub-sequences with equal sum are 
{1,2} {3}   // sum = 3
{1,3} {4}   // sum = 4
{2,3} {4,1} // sum = 5

Out of which 5 is the maximum sum.
```

**Eg 2:-**

```
6
1 2 4 5 9 1

Sub-sequence 1 : 2 4 5   // sum = 11
Sub-sequence 2 : 1 9 1   // sum = 11
The maximum sum you can get is 11
```

**Constraints:**

```
5 <= N <= 50

1<= number <=1000

sum of all numbers is <= 1000

Important: Only <iostream> can be used. No STLs.

N numbers are unsorted.

If array is not possible to split, print 0.

Number of function stacks is limited. ie your recursive/memoization solution won't work.
```

**Approach 1:**

I tried a recursive approach something like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool visited[51][1001][1001];
int arr[51];
int max_height=0;
int max_height_idx=0;
int N;

void recurse( int idx, int sum_left, int sum_right){
    if(sum_left == sum_right){
        if(sum_left > max_height){
            max_height = sum_left;
            max_height_idx = idx;
        }
    }


    if(idx>N-1)return ;

    if(visited[idx][sum_left][sum_right]) return ;

    recurse( idx+1, sum_left+arr[idx], sum_right);
    recurse( idx+1, sum_left         , sum_right+arr[idx]);
    recurse( idx+1, sum_left         , sum_right);

    visited[idx][sum_left][sum_right]=true;

    /*
       We could reduce the function calls, by check the visited condition before calling the function.
       This could reduce stack allocations for function calls. For simplicity I have not checking those conditions before function calls.
       Anyways, this recursive solution would get time out. No matter how you optimize it.
       Btw, there are T testcases. For simplicity, removed that constraint.
    */
}

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    recurse(0,0,0);

    cout<< max_height <<"\n";
}
```

`NOTE:` Passes test-cases. But time out.

**Approach 2:**

```
I also tried, taking advantage of constraints.

Every number has 3 possible choice:
    1. Be in sub-sequence 1
    2. Be in sub-sequence 2
    3. Be in neither of these sub-sequences 

So
    1. Be in sub-sequence 1 -> sum +  1*number
    2. Be in sub-sequence 2 -> sum + -1*number
    3. None             -> sum

Maximum sum is in range -1000 to 1000. 
So dp[51][2002] could be used to save the maximum positive sum achieved so far (ie till idx).
```

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[51];
int N;
int dp[51][2002];

int max3(int a, int b, int c){
    return max(a,max(b,c));
}
int max4(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return max(max(a,b),max(c,d));
}

int recurse( int idx, int sum){

    if(sum==0){
        // should i perform anything here?
    }

    if(idx>N-1){
        return 0;
    }

    if( dp[idx][sum+1000] ){
        return dp[idx][sum+1000];
    }

    return dp[idx][sum+1000] = max3 (
                                arr[idx] + recurse( idx+1, sum + arr[idx]),
                                    0    + recurse( idx+1, sum - arr[idx]),
                                    0    + recurse( idx+1, sum           )
                               )  ;

    /*
        This gives me a wrong output.

        4
        1 3 5 4
    */
}


int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    cout<< recurse(0,0) <<"\n";

}
```

The above code gives me wrong answer. Kindly help me with solving/correcting this memoization.

Also open to iterative approach for the same.

Comment: "2 equal sum subsets" -- do the subsets have to be from distinct entries of the original N?  Or can they reuse elements from the N?

Can you naively compute all of the possible subset pairs from N and select the ones whose sums match, then sort those?

Comment: An element belonging to Set A, cannot exist in Set B. But if there are say two 1's in the Universal Set, then Set A can have one 1, and Set B can have one 1.

Comment: computing all the possible subset would require almost (1<<50), ie 2^50. It is really not feasible.

Comment: Storing partial results of these computations is not feasible beyond N=20, ie 2^20 combinations.

Comment: *Important: Only <iostream> can be used. No STLs.* -- Which implies that if you did use STL, the solution would be simple.  So have you thought about which algorithm function(s) would do the job?  If so, then use those functions to see if they work, then rewrite the code without using those functions (but mimicking them instead).  Also, start out actually *using* STL -- solve the problem first.  You would have an idea, at least, what pattern(s) to use to solve the problem.

Comment: @BrianCain: If each subset could use an element, the answer would just be to put everything in each.

Comment: Are you sure the question doesn't mean to find *subsequences*? Subsets are supposed to be contiguous but the examples show otherwise.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Neither "subset" nor "subsequence" implies choosing consecutive items from an original sequence.

Comment: Changed `subset` to `subarray`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the test? I'd like to check a small modification to  your code.

Comment: I am really sorry. This was a hiring challenge question. The link is not available anymore. If it was an online contest, I could have checked the editorial / others_codes after the contest ends.

Comment: `I have removed all the storylines for this question.`—you have removed important parts about what exactly is "subarray" (subsequence/substring are more common terms) and if there are any restrictions on the chosen subarrays (one way is to prohibit choosing the same position from the array twice, but still allowing choosing the same value twice).

Comment: `Btw, there are T testcases. For simplicity, removed that constraint.`—again, this is important information which should not have been removed because it significantly affects running time of the solution and allows better estimations.

Comment: @Arjun I have added another dynamic programming based solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea of your second approach is correct, it's basically a reduction to [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). However, it looks like your code lacks **clear contract**: what the `recurse` function is supposed to do.

Here is my suggestion: `int recurse(int idx, int sum)` distributes elements on positions `idx..n-1` into three multisets `A`, `B`, `C` such that `sum+sum(A)-sum(B)=0` and returns maximal possible `sum(A)`, `-inf` otherwise (here `-inf` is some hardcoded constant which serves as a "marker" of no answer; there are some restrictions on it, I suggest `-inf == -1000`).

Now you're to write a recursive backtracking using that contract and then add memoization. Voila—you've got a dynamic programming solution.

In recursive backtracking we have two distinct situations:

1. There are no more elements to distribute, no choices to make: `idx == n`. In that case, we should check that our condition holds (`sum + sum(A) - sum(B) == 0`, i.e. `sum == 0`) and return the answer. If `sum == 0`, then the answer is 0. However, if `sum != 0`, then there is no answer and we should return something which will never be chosen as the answer, unless there are no answer for the whole problem. As we modify returning value of `recurse` and do not want extra `if`s, it cannot be simply zero or even `-1`; it should be a number which, when modified, still remains "the worst answer ever". The biggest modification we can make is to add all numbers to the resulting value, hence we should choose something less or equal to negative maximal sum of numbers (i.e. `-1000`), as existing answers are always strictly positive, and that fictive answer will always be non-positive.
2. There is at least one remaining element which should be distributed to either `A`, `B` or `C`. Make the choice and choose the best answer among three options. Answers are calculated recursively.

Here is my implementation:

```
const int MAXN = 50;
const int MAXSUM = 1000;

bool visited[MAXN + 1][2 * MAXSUM + 1]; // should be filled with false
int dp[MAXN + 1][2 * MAXSUM + 1]; // initial values do not matter

int recurse(int idx, int sum){
    // Memoization.
    if (visited[idx][sum + MAXSUM]) {
        return dp[idx][sum + MAXSUM];
    }
    // Mark the current state as visited in the beginning,
    // it's ok to do before actually computing it as we're
    // not expect to visit it while computing.
    visited[idx][sum + MAXSUM] = true;

    int &answer = dp[idx][sum + MAXSUM];

    // Backtracking search follows.
    answer = -MAXSUM;  // "Answer does not exist" marker.

    if (idx == N) {
        // No more choices to make.
        if (sum == 0) {
            answer = 0;  // Answer exists.
        } else {
            // Do nothing, there is no answer.
        }
    } else {
        // Option 1. Current elemnt goes to A.
        answer = max(answer, arr[idx] + recurse(idx + 1, sum + arr[idx]));
        // Option 2. Current element goes to B.
        answer = max(answer, recurse(idx + 1, sum - arr[idx]));
        // Option 3. Current element goes to C.
        answer = max(answer, recurse(idx + 1, sum));
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: ...Great answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you kindly provide your thoughts on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870973/5-cpus-task-scheduling-n-process

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple dynamic programming based solution for anyone interested, based on the idea suggested by Codeforces user `lemelisk` [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/54259?#comment-383268). Complete post [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/54259). I haven't tested this code completely though.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 20 // maximum length of array
#define MAXSUM 500 // maximum sum of all elements in array
#define DIFFSIZE (2*MAXSUM + 9) // possible size of differences array (-maxsum, maxsum) + some extra

int dp[MAXN][DIFFSIZE] = { 0 };
int visited[DIFFSIZE] = { 0 }; // visited[diff] == 1 if the difference 'diff' can be reached 
int offset = MAXSUM + 1; // offset so that indices in dp table don't become negative
// 'diff' replaced by 'offset + diff' below everywhere

int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
int max_3(int a, int b, int c) {
    return max(a, max(b, c));
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5};
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int *arr = new int[n + 1];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        arr[i] = a[i - 1]; // 'arr' same as 'a' but with 1-indexing for simplicity
        sum += arr[i];
    } // 'sum' holds sum of all elements of array

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIFFSIZE; j++)
            dp[i][j] = INT_MIN;
    }

    /*
    dp[i][j] signifies the maximum value X that can be reached till index 'i' in array such that diff between the two sets is 'j'
    In other words, the highest sum subsets reached till index 'i' have the sums {X , X + diff}
    See http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/54259 for details
    */

    // 1 ... i : (X, X + diff) can be reached by 1 ... i-1 : (X - a[i], X + diff)
    dp[0][offset] = 0; // subset sum is 0 for null set, difference = 0 between subsets
    visited[offset] = 1; // initially zero diff reached

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int diff = (-1)*sum; diff <= sum; diff++) {
            if (visited[offset + diff + arr[i]] || visited[offset + diff - arr[i]] || visited[offset + diff]) { 
                // if difference 'diff' is reachable, then only update, else no need
                dp[i][offset + diff] = max_3 
                (
                    dp[i - 1][offset + diff], 
                    dp[i - 1][offset + diff + arr[i]] + arr[i], 
                    dp[i - 1][offset + diff - arr[i]] 
                );
                visited[offset + diff] = 1;
            }
        }
        /*
        dp[i][diff] = max {
        dp[i - 1][diff] : not taking a[i] in either subset
        dp[i - 1][diff + arr[i]] + arr[i] : putting arr[i] in first set, thus reducing difference to 'diff', increasing X to X + arr[i]
        dp[i - 1][diff - arr[i]] : putting arr[i] in second set
        initialization: dp[0][0] = 0
        */

        // O(N*SUM) algorithm
    }
    cout << dp[n][offset] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`14`

Answer (score 0):

State is not updated in Approach 1. Change the last line of recurse

```
visited[idx][sum_left][sum_right];
```

to

```
visited[idx][sum_left][sum_right] = 1;
```

Also memset the visited array to false before calling recurse from main.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I missed out that part (I intended the same). Actually, I am looking for some help with my `second implementation`. Because `Approach 1` times out any ways.

Comment: Before abandoning approach 1 you should try to fine tune it. Instead of blindly trying all three possibilities (add_left, add_right, ignore) add a if block before calling the recursive method like if(sum_left + val[idx] <= half_total_sum) add_left.

Comment: The first approach had this condition: `if( idx >= max_height_idx && sum_left<=max_height ) 
 return ;` . But still, didn't pass. The catch is in the last constraint, `recursive call` is not suited here.